# Docker unexpectedly modify host file's owner / group

Tags: docker

My docker is running in a linux server (cluster-HP-Z440-Workstation).

Here, I build a container and use `-v` command to link files/directories to host machine.

```
docker run --name 20200708 -dp 5003:8787 -e ROOT=TRUE -e USER=user -e PASSWORD=password -v /home/user:/home/user rocker/tidyverse
```

After building the image, I found that docker change the ownership under linked directory to `cluster`, which was owned by the `user` before.

```
# The directory /home/user and the files inside are all become cluster/cluster

    drwxrwxr-x 2 cluster cluster 4.0K  七   7 18:02 download
    drwxrwxr-x 2 cluster cluster 4.0K  七   8 10:33 R Script
    drwxr-xr-x 3 cluster cluster 4.0K  七   7 23:25 rstudio
    drwxrwxr-x 3 cluster cluster 4.0K  七   7 18:08 TCGA_Firehose
```

After I take back the ownership by `chmod`, then, I found that I cannot save files inside container.

So I build another images with similar command, and again, the files/directories ownership are changed to cluster...

I don't understand why docker change the files/directories ownership?
Is there a way to fix the problem and allow program inside container to save files in the linked path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is (probably) normal.

If you read the documentation on the [rocker/rstudio](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio) image (the base image of `rocker/tidyverse`), you can find this sentence :

> Custom uid/gid etc is usually only needed when sharing a local volume for a user/group whose id does not match the default (1000:1000). Failing to do this could make files change permissions on the linked volume when accessed from RStudio

### So what happens ?

In fact, when you run a Docker image, there is something called *user mapping* between your host user and the container user. This mechanism takes the container user uid and try to map it with a host user uid if it exists.

A classic example is when you execute a command inside a container as root, you'll see that you have root permission on your host. This is because the root uid is *always* the same (0).

Now, back to your problem, to see why you're container user is mapped to the `cluster` user of your host, you just need to get the user uid inside your container :

```
# inside your container, run the "id" command
user@host: id
```

This will print the uid/gid of the current user. Now you can search for the user on your host whose id match (inside you `/etc/passwd` file). You'll probably see the **cluster** user.

### How to resolve this ?

Simple : use another user, or map the container user with another user. You can find some info [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/).

Also try not to map your home directory if possible (so that the impact is less important when you have this kind of situation)

Comment: Thanks! It's indeed caused by different user id between local volume and container. I followed the information described in [rocker/rstudio](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio), and set another two parameter `-e USERID=<UID>, -e GROUPID=<GID>`. And it works.